# SQL Query for a list of dates

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I am trying to to do a pretty basic query in which I'm trying to match multiple factors from two tables. I'm having problems with the fact that one of the fields I want to match is the date field.  I'm not trying to find a date range.  i am trying to match specific dates from a list.  I have tried

`INNER JOIN...ON Table1.Date = Table2.Date`,

`WHERE Table1.Date - Table2.Date`

```
WHERE Table1.Date IN (*list of dates)'*
```

The gist of the query is

```
SELECT *fields* FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.field1 = Table2.field1 
AND Table1.field2 = Table2.Field2
```

This is where I get stuck.

Amy I doing something wrong with the where clause?  The list of dates?  The Join using the dates?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: In your DB what is the data type of the `Date` column?

Comment: In both of the tables the date is in the 'Date/Time' format according to the design view in MS Access.

Comment: What happened when you tried in (list of dates)?

Comment: @Longdaysjourneyintocode Do you care about the time?  It could be that one table has value 1/1/2014 8:00:00 and the other has 1/1/2014 11:25:22 and that is throwing you off.

Comment: @DanBracuk When I tried 'in (list of dates), I get a 'syntax error (missing operator)'  Should I have quotes around the dates?

Comment: @Donal Can you explain more?  The dates are a list of dates, not a particular timeframe.

Comment: @Donal [NEVER USE BETWEEN](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)!

Comment: Are you getting these list's of dates from somewhere or are you just typing them in?

Comment: From your prose, in (list of dates) is the correct approach.  Edit your question you show the code that threw the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1 AND t1.field2 = t2.Field2
WHERE 
t1.Date IN (select t3.date from table2 t3)
```